# Count values in column E if the date in column F is greater than today

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do you count values in column E if the date in column F is greater than today.

This is what i have so far - but it returns 0.

```
=COUNTIF(E:E,F:F>=TODAY())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(E:E,"<>",F:F,">="&TODAY())
```

Comment: it returns TRUE and not a value

Comment: Yes it works fine - would it look like this if it was SUMIFS? `=SUMIFS(E:E,"<>",F:F,">="&TODAY())`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to use column E at all. The number of corresponding cells in E is the same as the number of column F cells matching criteria. It is irrelevant to finding the number of values in column F greater than today. First parameter is the range you want to count values in and the second is just the criteria. Try this:

```
=COUNTIF(F:F,">="&TODAY())
```

Comment: Possibly. If so that is just one added condition (COUNTIF --> COUNTIFS) which I won't add since it seems you already put that as another answer.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using sumproduct.  THis can be used to count and find a weighted average.  For counting, you wrap the range in --() and anything within that row is counted as 1.  If you include a conditional statement, the row is only counted if the condition is true.  You can add several conditions to filter out more data as needed.  In the field below, I have the current date set to F12 or you can use the current date.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E2:E10),--(F2:F10>F12))
```

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a bit of confusion about wether you want to count or sum the values in column E if the date is equal to or greater than todays.

Here's the sum formula

```
=SUM(IF(F2:F5>=TODAY(),E2:E5,0))
```

Hit ctrl+alt+delete so you get the curly brackets.
It should look like `{=SUM(IF(F2:F5>=TODAY(),E2:E5,0))}`

Use the same formula but with count if you want it to count.

```
=count(IF(F2:F5>=TODAY(),E2:E5,0))
```

Again, use ctrl+alt+delete

Comment: The original question mentioned that he wants to compare the date in column F and didnt mention it could contain any other type of data. If that's the case, then the answer would be valid as he/she didn't ask for the formula to validate if the value was a cell.